# Executing a command string with GO at the end

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to execute a command string with using GO command at the end like

```
exec('SELECT * FROM tblTmp where Id = 1 GO')
```

After executing I have

> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

If I execute `exec('SELECT * FROM tblTmp GO')` everything is OK

What's the issue here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use GO for a single SQL statement. Only when you're batching several statements into a single script do you need to use a separator. Also, if you're executing these programmatically you should be using the semicolon (;) statement terminator instead of GO to separate your SQL statement.

Here's a handy [SQL Server Central article on the usage of GO and the semicolon](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Puzzles/thegocommandandthesemicolonterminator/2200/).

Comment: `GO` separates batches, while `;` separates statements. For most statements (`WITH` and `MERGE` being notable exceptions) you don't even need a semicolon. Say, this: `EXEC('SELECT 1 SELECT 2')` works nice even without a semicolon.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Modified my verbiage a little and added a link to nice discussion on the topic. As far as using semicolons, there seem to be two schools of thought, but, I have run into situations where adding a semicolon to separate statements has made a difference. The usage was complex, multi-statement T-SQL scripts assembled client-side and pushed to the server for processing. I wish I recalled more detailed particulars but I don't.

Comment: as I said, `WITH` and `MERGE` are the most notable exceptions, and there are lots of less notable.

Answer (score 18):

`GO` is not an `SQL` command, it is a batch separator understood by clients like `osql`, `sqlcmd`, and `SSMS` but not the engine itself.

If you write something like this in `SSMS`:

```
SELECT  1
GO
SELECT  2
GO
```

, the engine sends two batches with one statement in each instead of one batch with two statements.

In your second query, `GO` is treated as an alias to the table `tblTmp`.

Just remove `GO` from your query.

Comment: How can I send batch with using exec('...')?

Comment: @Vyacheslav: by providing the batch text as an argument to `EXEC`, without a trailing `GO`. You cannot send more than one batch in a single `EXEC`.